# Powershell as Default Shell in NeoVim

Tags: lua, neovim

I'm not entirely sure how to set powershell as the default terminal with neovim. I'm using an init.lua file but have no idea how to set things correctly.

Does anyone know the right syntax for setting this correctly?

Thanks,
Mitchell

Answer (score 2):

Running `:h :terminal` shows the following:

> Execute {cmd} with 'shell' in a new terminal buffer

So use `:set shell=path/to/powershell` or in your init.lua file, you can add `vim.o.shell = "path/to/powershell`.

In my case, I'm able to simply set it to `"powershell.exe"` via `:set shell=powershell.exe` or `vim.o.shell. = "powershell.exe"` and it works perfectly, but you may need to fully qualify your path if it's not in PATH.